# How can I control for time-varying unobserved heterogeneity with panel data?

Tags: econometrics, panel-data, fixed-effects-model, causality

I'm just beginning to learn econometrics, and I just learned about the fixed effects estimator, and the first-difference estimator. It's quite straightforward that those techniques allow me to control for time-invariant unobserved heterogeneity.

However, I cannot stop wondering: What if an omitted variable is time-varying? How can I take care of that problem?

I would appreciate an overall answer without any sophisticated explications.

Comment: This question seems clear enough to me. I'm voting to leave open.

Comment: it is possible to include time fixed effect in the model instead of case fixed effect. This way all the case-invariant but time-varying heterogeneity will drop out.

Comment: It's worth mentioning Pesaran's tests for panel unit roots and cross-sectional dependence while acknowledging that they are not specific to your question. https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1002/jae.951 https://www.google.com/books/edition/Time_Series_and_Panel_Data_Econometrics/MsOPCgAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=0

Answer (score 0):

### Unfortunately I don't think there is a way

One can control for heterogeneity using e.g. fixed effects under the assumption that it is time-invariant, and that the correct level of aggregation is known (e.g. individual vs. group fixed effects).
I think the reason why it may seem like something similar may be possible for time-variant heterogeneity is because the word "unobserved" is often used in the context of fixed effects. So if we can control for one "unobserved" thing, why not for another?
Unfortunately, "unobserved" is a bit of a misnomer. The fixed effect may consist of components that are not observed individually, but the aggregate is in fact observed by knowing how to group observations (e.g. belonging to the same individual, country, etc.).
**There is no way to control for a truly unobserved variable, no matter if time-varying or fixed.**
Imagine for example that there are distinct groups which deserve their own fixed effect, but you would not know which observation belongs to which group – it would be unclear how to even define the fixed effects. In the case of time-varying unobserved heterogeneity this is more obvious still. One could imagine this as individual fixed effects that interact with time fixed effects, without knowing what time or individual fixed effects to choose.

In summary, one cannot control for unobserved heterogeneity, no matter if time-varying or not. It is simply the case that the word "unobserved" is sometimes used in the context of time-invariant heterogeneity which is only observed in aggregate through group-membership.

Answer (score 0):

The interactive fixed effects models is designed to handle such cases: https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.3982/ecta6135

This is basically a factor model for fixed effects.